# move image by point offset from center in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uipangesturerecognizer

Im moving images around the iPhone screen using UIPanGesture. Some of the images are small and when you move them around your finger obscures your view of the image itself. I want to set the center of the image, while its being moved, so that the image center is actually 10 points in front of the touch location instead of setting it to the touch location.

I tested the below but quickly realized that it repeatedly subtracts 10 from the Y making the image get further and further away from the touch location and eventually off the screen rather than maintaining a constant 10 point offset.

How should I be doing this?

```
- (void) TestGestureMethod:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) panGesture {
    CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:self.view];
    switch (panGesture.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:testObject];
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        testObject.center = CGPointMake(testObject.center.x + translation.x,
                                        testObject.center.y + translation.y);
        testObject.center = CGPointMake(testObject.center.x, testObject.center.y - 10);
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        break;
    }
    [panGesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're not translating the image but manually setting its center, have you considered using UIGestureRecognizer locationInView: instead of translationInView:?

You could do something like this...

```
- (void)TestGestureMethod:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGesture
{
    CGPoint location = [panGesture locationInView:self.view];

    switch (panGesture.state) {
        ...
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            testObject.center = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y - 10);
        break;
        ... 
    }
}
```

This should cause the image center to always be at just 10 points below the touch.

Comment: is there a way to animate the sudden move the object makes when first dragging? maybe resizing it, or adding a spring action?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void) TestGestureMethod:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) panGesture {
    CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:self.view];
    switch (panGesture.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:testObject];
        testObject.center = CGPointMake(testObject.center.x, testObject.center.y - 10);
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        testObject.center = CGPointMake(testObject.center.x + translation.x,
                                        testObject.center.y + translation.y);

        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        break;
    }
    [panGesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, this solves ur problem:

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UIView *piece = [gestureRecognizer view];

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[piece superview]];

        [piece setCenter:CGPointMake([piece center].x + translation.x, [piece center].y + translation.y)];
        [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[piece superview]];
    }
}
```

I hope this will helps you.